# AbstractStatelessSessionBean missing from SpringFramework 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-4, spring2.x

I'm trying to update a big projekt from Spring 2 to Spring 4.
On the deep end of the Beans hierarchy i found a class called `CustomAbstractStatelessSessionBean` and that extends the `AbstractStatelessSessionBean` class from `org.springframework.ejb.support.AbstractStatelessSessionBean`.

The content of the class:

```
public abstract class CustomAbstractStatelessSessionBean extends

AbstractStatelessSessionBean{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8467612263077285422L;

    @Override
    public void setSessionContext(SessionContext sessionContext) {
        LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor asd =new LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor;

        super.setSessionContext(sessionContext);

        setBeanFactoryLocatorKey("global.spring.ejb.context");
        setBeanFactoryLocator(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Be patient Spring rookie here! :D

Every idea or workaround is welcomed!

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is there a workaround? As i see the only reason for this anchestor class is to set the context. Is there any interface that is capable of that?

Comment: The class doesn't exist anymore because it is old, it dates back to the old EJB specs and hence has been removed. There is no replacement you can get the source from an older spring version and add it to your own project and use that. Else figure out what is needed exactly from the `AbstractStatelessSessionBean` and make a minimal implementation for that. Or refactor to not have to use the EJB at all.

Comment: Okey. I will find some older source :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

The best workaround was to find the source and copy it :)
It's a very thin layer between the javax and the spring classes.

Is it possible to mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: This workaround did not work for me.  Am I missing something here ? I believe the AbstractStatelessSessionBean allows to setSessionContext, but I am not able to set it without support to this class.

Comment: Damn you must be working on some very old code cause it was legacy thing 5 years ago. I guess your problem is that the setSessionContext was removed(it was only deprecated in that time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to find the source of the spring classes and copy it.
It was a very thin layer between the spring class and the real javax classes :)